# variable nested for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to figure out how I can use recursion to do n-level nested for loops.
For example, if n=3, there would be 3 'levels'

```
for(z=0;z<6;z++){
   for(y=0;y<6;y++){
      for(x=0;x<6;x++){
         if (z+y+x==f){
            //do something
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

and so on.

I can't seem to figure out how I would be able to place the if loop in the last for loop and how I can access the variables of previous for loops from the if statement. I know that the question of variable nested loops has been asked alot of times, and I have looked through all of them. But none seem to help me.

Could someone present an easy way of using recursion to achieve this, keeping in mind that I'm still a beginner in c++, to point me in the right direction?

The use case is as follows:

> Write a program to input the number of dice m. The program will output the total number of possible cases, the number of possible cases for each possible n and the n with the highest probability. Note: only one input m is read in. n is computed by the program
>
> Example if user enters m=2 then program should output
>
> The total number of possible cases is 36.
>   The possibilities are  
>   2  1 
>   3  2 
>   4  3 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   12 1

Comment: Typo in the second loop?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why use recursion?

Comment: I am just wondering how this can be achieved with recursion.

Comment: What VJovic said. It's not clear what you're trying to do. Splitting this up into recursive function calls somewhat seems goalless. We need to see more about how you'd like it to look. "with recursion" is too vague. Also, there is no such thing as an "if loop"

Comment: I understand that this can be achieved iteratively. But I would like to know how this can achieved recursively.

Comment: @cortex: Can you explain what it is about our comments that you do not understand? My answer will have to be guesswork because you're refusing to provide any context or detail, instead just repeating the same words over and over again. That's _really_ frustrating.

Comment: Sorry. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: It still doesn't explain why you think you need recursion, or in what way / to what extent you want the loop to be reformed recursively.

Comment: I don't NEED recursion to solve this problem. I would like to try a different method of solving the problem and hence asking the community for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example in plain old C++. First I make a vector of the ranges for each dimension called `maxes`. if the sum of all indices are 2 then I print did something. 
In the example I loop z from 0 to 1, y from 0 to 2, x from 0 to 3

You can for sure make this more neat.

Here goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int f(){ 
    return 2 ;
}

void inner(int depth,vector<int> & numbers,vector<int> & maxes){
  if (depth>0){
     for(int i=0;i<maxes[depth-1];i++){
        numbers[depth-1]=i;
        inner(depth-1, numbers,maxes) ;
     }
  }else{
     // calculate sum of x,y,z:
     cout << "values are ";
     for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
        cout <<numbers[i]<<" ";
     }
     int thesum(0);
     for(int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
        thesum+=numbers[i];
     }
     if (thesum==f()){
        cout << "did something! ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
   }
}

void donest(){
   vector<int>  numbers;
   numbers.resize(3);
   vector<int>  maxes;
   maxes.push_back(4);
   maxes.push_back(3);
   maxes.push_back(2);
   inner(numbers.size(),numbers,maxes);
}

int main(){
   donest();
}
```

result:

```
values are 0 0 0 
values are 1 0 0 
values are 2 0 0  did something! 
values are 3 0 0 
values are 0 1 0 
values are 1 1 0  did something! 
values are 2 1 0 
values are 3 1 0 
values are 0 2 0  did something! 
values are 1 2 0 
values are 2 2 0 
values are 3 2 0 
values are 0 0 1 
values are 1 0 1  did something! 
values are 2 0 1 
values are 3 0 1 
values are 0 1 1  did something! 
values are 1 1 1 
values are 2 1 1 
values are 3 1 1 
values are 0 2 1 
values are 1 2 1 
values are 2 2 1 
values are 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 17):

For efficiency, I've avoided recursion. Also, it doesn't use any specific c++ stuff - it will work fine on C as well.

We're trying to create N nested "for" loops.
Instead of using

```
for(int i = 0; i<max; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j<max; j++)
    ...
```

I'll be replacing i, j, ... with an array: i[0], i[1], ..., i[n-1].

Here's my solution:

```
const int n = /*Insert N here: how many loops do you need?*/;
int i[n+1]; // if "n" is not known before hand, then this array will need to be created dynamically.
//Note: there is an extra element at the end of the array, in order to keep track of whether to exit the array.

for (int a=0; a<n+1; a++) {
  i[a]=0;
}

int MAX = 79; //That's just an example, if all of the loops are identical: e.g. "for(int i=0; i<79; i++)". If the value of MAX changes for each loop, then make MAX an array instead: (new) int MAX [n]; MAX[0]=10; MAX[1]=20;...;MAX[n-1]=whatever.

int p = 0; //Used to increment all of the indicies correctly, at the end of each loop.
while (i[n]==0) {//Remember, you're only using indicies i[0], ..., i[n-1]. The (n+1)th index, i[n], is just to check whether to the nested loop stuff has finished.

  //DO STUFF HERE. Pretend you're inside your nested for loops. The more usual i,j,k,... have been replaced here with i[0], i[1], ..., i[n-1].


  //Now, after you've done your stuff, we need to increment all of the indicies correctly.
  i[0]++;
  // p = 0;//Commented out, because it's replaced by a more efficient alternative below.
  while(i[p]==MAX) {//(or "MAX[p]" if each "for" loop is different. Note that from an English point of view, this is more like "if(i[p]==MAX". (Initially i[0]) If this is true, then i[p] is reset to 0, and i[p+1] is incremented.
    i[p]=0;
    i[++p]++; //increase p by 1, and increase the next (p+1)th index
    if(i[p]!=MAX)
      p=0;//Alternatively, "p=0" can be inserted above (currently commented-out). This one's more efficient though, since it only resets p when it actually needs to be reset!
  }
}
```

There, that's all. Hopefully the comments make it clear what it's meant to be doing. I think it should be pretty efficient - almost as much as real nested for-loops. Most of the overhead is a one-off at the beginning, so this should be more efficient that using recursive functions etc

Answer (score 10):

The basic structure of a recursive algorithm with multiple loops is as follows:

```
void recursiveLoops(vector<int>& indexes, const vector<int>& endPerIndex, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == indexes.size()) {
        // This is where the real logic goes.
        // indexes[i] contain the value of the i-th index.
    } else {
        for (indexes[pos] = 0 ; indexes[pos] != endPerIndex[pos] ; indexes[pos]++) {
            // Recurse for the next level
            recursiveLoops(indexes, endPerIndex, pos+1);
        }
    }
}
```

The setup for calling `recursiveLoops` from the top level requires two vectors - one for the indexes, and one for the number of iterations at each level. The example below sets up three nested loops, iterating 5, 6, and 9 times at each level:

```
vector<int> indexes(3, 0);
vector<int> endPerIndex;
endPerIndex.push_back(5);
endPerIndex.push_back(6);
endPerIndex.push_back(9);
recursiveLoops(indexes, endPerIndex, 0);
```

Comment: One typical problem for recursive functions is stack overflow. For variable level nested for-loop, this is very likely to happen.  I know our vendor hard-coded their loops to max level of nests of 5 and they said they will raise the limitation to 9. Three years past they still have not done that, lol.

Answer (score 0):

just count the depth for each recursion function, and count to `f`..

```
void myRecursiveFunc(int depth){
   if(depth == f)
      //do something
      return;
   else{
      myRecursiveFunc(depth + 1);
   }
}
```

if you really want you can use three different functions for x,y and z.

Comment: Well, @Lightness. My problem is as follows.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this, but... I wouldn't. It's confusing code and doesn't give you any benefits. If you want it because your true use case has a high number of nested loops, consider just not doing that, instead; it's a serious design smell.

```
void nested_loop(const int levels, const int comparator, const int level = 0, const int accumulator = 0)
{
   if (level < levels) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         nested_loop(levels, comparator, level + 1, accumulator + i);
      }
   }
   else {
      if (accumulator == comparator) {   // your if (z+y+x==f)
         //do something
      }
   }
}

int main() {
   const int levels = 3;
   const int f = 42;

   nested_loop(levels, f);
}
```

### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/p3Ak2).

Answer (score 0):

You are very vague about why you want this. For a starter a possible solution is to replace each for loop with a recursive function.

```
void recursiveX(int zVal, int yVal, int xVal)
{
    if(zVal+yVal+xVal == f)...
    if(xVal != 0)
        recursiveX(zVal, yVal, xVal -1);
}

void recursiveY(int zVal, int yVal)
{
    recursiveX(zVal, yVal, 6);
    if(yVal != 0)
        recursiveY(zVal, yVal-1);
}

void recursiveZ(int val)
{
    recursiveY(val, 6);
    if(val != 0)
        recursiveZ(val-1);
}
...
recursiveZ(6);
```

And in the end you can merge this all into one function. Nevertheless using recursion just because it is possible is never a good Idea.

Answer (score 0):

### Variable loop using while loop in "C".

#### Concept

1. Creating a 2-dimensional array (arr[level][2]) in which first element is starting, and second element is end.

   `x[3][2] = {{0, 10}, {5, 20}, {2, 60}};`
2. Creating another array with starting elements.

   `y[3] = {0, 5, 2};`
3. We created a second array, because during the loop we will change the first element of "x" array.

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
// bruteforce
int level = 10;
int start[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int x[10][2] = {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}};


for (int i = 1;i < level; ++i){
    x[i][1] = x[i][1] + 1;
}
while(3>2){
    // Your code here



   // 

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", x[0][0], x[1][0], x[2][0], x[3][0]);


    // variable loop code
    // ==== Not To Modify ====
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < level; ++i){
        if (x[i][0] >= x[i][1])
        {
                if(i != level-1){
                    x[i][0] = start[i];
                    x[i+1][0] = x[i+1][0] + 1;
                }else{
                    a = 1;
                }
                b = 1;
            
        }else{
            if(b == 0){
                x[0][0] = x[0][0] + 1;
                b = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(a == 1){
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but maybe it will help someone.

Here is my solution in c++ without recursive function.:

```
int n_loops{3}; //number of nested for loops

int loops_idx[n_loops]; //like i,j,k but in an array
for (int i = 0; i < n_loops; i++)
    loops_idx[i]=0;

int max_idx[n_loops]{3,2,4}; // like in for(; i < counter ;), but the counters in an array

bool is_finished = false;
int debug_n_of_execution{0};

while (!is_finished)
{
    for (; loops_idx[0]<max_idx[0]; loops_idx[0]++)
    {
        /*
        some code with loops_idx array as i,j,k...
        */
        ++debug_n_of_execution;
        for (int i = 0; i < n_loops; i++)
            std::cout<<loops_idx[i]<<" ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    --loops_idx[0]; //to cancel last increment
    //Here it will increment the last loop_idx which isn't equal to max_idx[i]-1
    //eg. after first above for loop loops_idx will be (max-1, 0, 0)
    //So it will be after this loop (0, 1, 0) and start from the beginning...
    for (int i = 0; i < n_loops+1; i++) //+1 to know if all loops are finished
    {
        if (i == n_loops)
        {is_finished= true; break;}

        if(loops_idx[i]==max_idx[i]-1)
            continue;
        
        ++loops_idx[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) //make any previous loop = 0  
            loops_idx[j]=0;
        
        break;
    }
}

//just to check
int debug_perfect_n_of_execution{max_idx[0]};
for (int i = 1; i < n_loops; i++)
    debug_perfect_n_of_execution*= max_idx[i];
std::cout<<"Number of execution: "<<debug_n_of_execution<<" = "<<debug_perfect_n_of_execution;
assert(debug_n_of_execution==debug_perfect_n_of_execution);
std::cout << "\nTests Finished";
```

And here is the result:

```
0 0 0 
1 0 0
2 0 0
0 1 0
1 1 0
2 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
2 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
2 1 1
0 0 2
1 0 2
2 0 2
0 1 2
1 1 2
2 1 2
0 0 3
1 0 3
2 0 3
0 1 3
1 1 3
2 1 3
Number of execution: 24 = 24
Tests Finished
```